# get node from firebase database to textviex with id

Tags: java, android, firebase

I would like to get "driverId" from "ride_info" and

if "driverId" is equal to a node in "Drivers" retrieve from this node "car", "license", "name", "phone",

and display it in a TEXTVIEW.

same for "customerId" get "name" and "phone"

i try this but it don't work it show me "null" on the textview

```
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query lastQuery = ref.child("Users").orderByKey();
    lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                String value1_float = ds.child("Drivers").child("car").getValue(String.class);
                String value0_float = ds.child("Drivers").child("name").getValue(String.class);
                String carname = String.valueOf(value0_float);
                String namnam = String.valueOf(value1_float);
                carName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.carname);
                carName.setText(carname);

                nameName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.namName);
                nameName.setText(namnam);

            }
            /** mDate.setText(mRide.getDate());
             mDestination.setText(mRide.getDestination().getName());
             mPickup.setText(mRide.getPickup().getName());
             mCar.setText(mRide.getCar());**/

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

[screenshot of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmtQq.png)

Comment: please look the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you you missed one field. That's why it returns null.
It must be like

```
ds.child("Drivers").child("IDlK2HRy......").child("car").getValue(String.class);
```

but this is also wrong because you used datasnapshot.getChildern() so `Drivers` child will be omited.

In case you don't know the in between child you can try like below for Drivers

```
Query lastQuery = ref.child("Users").child("Drivers").orderByKey();
    lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                carName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.carname);
                nameName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.namName);

                carName.setText(ds.child("name").getValue(String.class));
                nameName.setText(ds.child("car").getValue(String.class));
            }    
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```